# Call a function in a directive with isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

A coworker has created a directive with isolate scope and an internal controller that has a couple of functions on it. The functions are being called from within other directives simply by using `$scope.myFunction()` or from inside another function `this.myFunction()`. There is no binding that I can find.

I don't understand how this works and I cannot find any information on it, nor get this technique to work myself.

Comment: Add *some* illustrative code. Who is calling whom and how

Comment: Although you say you can't get it to work, it'll be easier to answer your question if you could post the code of a minimal example.

Comment: Why not ask the coworker?

Comment: This may clear things up: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-directive-to-directive-communication

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, I was misinformed. He was calling parent functions from the child. In angular you can't call functions on a child directive with isolate scope unless you expose them as a sort of api.

Create an object on the parent scope:
$scope.childDirective = {};

On the child scope:
accessor: "="

Bind them in the child directive attribute list:
""

Then add functions to accessor in the directive and they may be called by name from the parent.

Here's where I learned how to do this:
https://lennilobel.wordpress.com/tag/calling-directive-from-controller/